# Is there a way to link to a section header in an answer?

Tags: support, answers, hyperlinks

Is there a way to link to part of an answer, e.g. a section header within the answer? For example, I wanted to add a link in my profile to a section header in one of my answers that prefaces general information about that type of problem, while skipping the first part.

I don't think this is possible, but if it is, how can I do it? If it's not possible, this isn't a feature request by any means, since it's probably quite a specific notion that may not find much use.

Comment: A related feature request: [Automatically add id attributes to headers to enable link targeting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89314/335251)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply "quote" yourself using the markdown `>` character and then provide a link to the full post...

Comment: I'll probably do so if this isn't possible. Since the part of the post in question was a bit long, I hesitated to put the entire piece of text in my profile. +1 for a simple possible solution, though!

Comment: @Ricardo AFAIK, what you're suggesting is not supported by the current system +1

Comment: @gobernador I Was fairly sure of that, but it never hurts to ask.

Comment: @Ricardo It's unfortunate, but I believe the justification for it is too much work for not enough benefit. It just wouldn't be used enough to make it worthwhile to implement.

Comment: @gobernador I figured that, hence the last paragraph of my question. It's a feature that I might find useful in one or two instances, but not much more (which is why I did not mark my question as a feature request, but rather a discussion to check if I had missed something).

Comment: Umm ... Lix's recommendation is not even remotely like a section link.