# How to set the specific part links in questions or answers to jump to them with Markdown Editing?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, markdown, hyperlinks

As shown below, I'm trying to set the specific part links in an answer to jump to them with **Markdown editing** on **Stack Overflow**:

[image]

```html
<p id="part-link1">Part Link 1</p>

<p id="part-link2">Part Link 2</p>

<p id="part-link3">Part Link 3</p>
```

But, they don't have **ids** to jump to them (on **Google Chrome**) as shown below, so it's impossible to jump to them:

[image]

[image]

So, how can I set the specific part links in questions or answers to jump to them with Markdown editing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to link to a section header in an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140594/is-there-a-way-to-link-to-a-section-header-in-an-answer) (also related: [Automatically add id attributes to headers to enable link targeting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89314/1017231))

Comment: See section [7.5](https://pretextbook.org/examples/sample-article/html/section-7.html#subsection-12) of the MathJax documentation for an example of using anchors in MathJax.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: "[How to set the specific part links in questions or answers to jump to them with Markdown Editing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420785/3773011)", which is closed as a duplicate of "[How can I create a Table of Contents (ToC) to content within a Stack Overflow article?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416722/3773011)" and "[Allow links to reference the headers in answers (or questions)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388438/3773011)"

Comment: Our duplicate is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37894/282094 (cross-site here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12674/510296) and instructions for our sites that have MathJax enabled is here: "[How to label equations on the left with mathjax?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31046/510296)"